How to distinguish if Technic connectors without a Lego logo are genuine
I have a number of Technic like pieces which don't have Lego logo on them. See images below, where always one piece has a Lego logo on them but the other doesn't.
I'm wondering if they are genuine but maybe older Lego or some other brand like COBI because of the narrow high C symbol in a circle.




I'm not saying it's the case here, but it might be that they just moved the logo somewhere else.

I looked carefully and I didn't find the Lego logo anywhere else (for the pieces which don't have the logo on the picture)
